# General Strategy to show an estimator is admissible?

Tags: estimators, decision-theory, admissibility

I am getting into decision theory and I was wondering if there was a general way to check if a an estimator is admissible.

(PS This question might have already been asked, sorry if that is the case I checked before posting this and I could not find anything )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Complete Class Theorems, all admissible estimators are [Bayes estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule#Admissibility_of_(generalized)_Bayes_rules) or limits of them.

Comment: As far as I understand it, this is sometimes true and sometimes not, depending on what assumptions you make. This is why there are many complete class theorem**s** and not one complete class theorem. So for this to be a reasonable answer to the question, you'd have to be a lot more specific.